# aws elasticsearch created 2 instance but says it has 3 nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticsearch

First I had a cluster with one node. I've increased one instance(node) so now it should show that I have 2 nodes but instead it says I have 3. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will be temporarily since AWS follows blue/green deployment model. Please see this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elasticsearch-more-nodes/).

When you have a cluster with `1` node and `add 1 more node`, AWS ES will create a `new` cluster with `2` nodes and then copy the entire data set from older cluster to new one. While the `copying / migration` operation is in progress, you'll see `3` nodes - 2 from new cluster and 1 from old cluster. Once migration is completed, the node belonging to older cluster is deleted.